# How to define specific boundaries within a div while using the mousemove function

Tags: javascript, css, mousemove

I want to be able to have a small marker follow the movement of the mouse while being refined to a certain shape that's **not** a perfect rectangle. I am working from an existing jsfiddle that I found did very close to what I want, but not exactly what I need. 
Here is where I am right now: http://jsfiddle.net/twjeffer/3964w/1106/ 

The issues with the above, I am trying to keep the yellow dot within the T shape, not the entire div. My own thoughts on how to make this work was either 
A) working with 2 different divs that make up the "T", or
B) define the boundaries of the yellow marker by the "T" shape.
 I have been stuck on this for a while, any help or advice would be appreciated!

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, 

        limitX = $('.container').width() - 15,
            limitY = $('.container').height() - 15;

$(window).mousemove(function(e){
  var offset = $('.container').offset() ;
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
   if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
   if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 30;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 30;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the "follower" position to be outside the divs whenever mouse enters onto a div.

```
if(mouseX <= 45 && mouseY >= 45){ // if mouse enters first rectangle set it to edge of rectangle, similar procedure for second rectangle
    if(mouseX <= 45){
        mouseX = 50
    }
    if(mouseY >= 45){
        mouseY = 45
    }
}
```

Its just a starting point,can be improved to set mouseX and mouseY precisely I am just placing the "follower" at the edge of rectangles.

http://jsfiddle.net/u7sj6428/

Comment: Thank you for the advice! It's working much better now. I am working with this right now http://jsfiddle.net/twjeffer/u7sj6428/1/

Loads better! The only problem left is the follower crossing over at the corners. Any idea on how to fix that? 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First observation suggests that the problem you mentioned is because of damping speed.

Comment: oh interesting! thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to keep working on this on my own, but thanks for all of the help!